# How to load relations with { json:api } Client?

Tags: laravel, json-api

I am using the [{json:api} Client](https://github.com/swisnl/json-api-client) to parse json into Eloquent like models.

I have two models, `Congress` and `Speaker`. A `Congress` has many `Speaker`.

This is what I was able to do:

```
$repository = app(App\Repositories\CongressRepository::class);
$document = $repository->all();
```

`$document` is a `CollectionDocument` with the following attributes:

[image]

I would like to get the `speakers` of the first `Congress`. This is what I tried

```
$congresses = $document->getData();
$congress = $congresses->first();
$congress->speakers // <- this is null!
```

Why is `$congress->speakers` null? I also tried to us `$repository->all(['includes' => 'speakers']);` 
but this makes no differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `$congress->speakers` was null because the relation was null:

[image]

I use [this](https://github.com/cloudcreativity/laravel-json-api)  package to create the `json` output. Inside the `Schema.php` I had to add `self::DATA` to make the data visible, as explained in the [docs](https://laravel-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/schemas/#relationships).

```
public function getRelationships($resource, $isPrimary, array $includeRelationships)
{
    return [
        'speakers' => [
            self::SHOW_SELF => true,
            self::SHOW_RELATED => true,
            self::DATA => function () use ($resource) {
                return $resource->speakers;
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

I still wonder if its possible to load the relation, if only the `link` is given in the `API`.